# Getting "The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly." while trying to self-host SignalR with Owin

Tags: c#, .net, windows, signalr, owin

I'm trying to develop a Windows Form application that self-hosts SignalR through the use of OWIN.

I have found a couple of examples out there and they all point generally to something similar to the code bellow.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080";
        using (WebApplication.Start<MyStartUp>(url))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running on {0}", url));
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}

internal class MyStartUp
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        HubConfiguration config = new HubConfiguration {
            EnableCrossDomain = true
        };

        app.MapHubs(config);
    }
}
```

When I run the example, though, I consistently get the error "The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly." on the following line:

```
app.MapHubs(config);
```

I have found a few articles out there about the general error, which has to do with (obviously) a problem with custom Performance Counters. Nonetheless none of the possible solutions I found seem to be of any help, mainly because, well, it's suppose to be an issue with a custom counter, not a regular .Net framework counter missing.

Has anyone found a similar problem or can shed some light into the matter?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While I cannot explain why this happens, in my experience it is not a fatal error. See for example the response to [this issue](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1875). Therefore I would suggest that you ignore the exception and hope that if a further exception occurs that provides further insight into your underlying problem.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Unfortunately I'm unable to move past this point. I did find an article about hosting SignalIR locally. I'm going to give it a try and post the link here if it works.

Comment: I also cannot move past this as it causes <air quotes>"unit tests" to fail that I don't have the authority to eliminate. Any light to shine on this?